# JSON Deserialize (Newtonsoft) with same name properties and array

Tags: c#, json

So I have this json result:

```
{"status":"1","message":"OK","result":{"status":"0"}}
```

and I want to grab the 0 status.

**My code:**

```
public class getTXStatus
    {
        [JsonProperty("result")]
        public string status { get; set; }
    }  



public void GetTXStatus()
    {
        StartCoroutine(GetTXStatusAsync($"https://api.blablabla"));
    }

    IEnumerator GetTXStatusAsync(string url)
    {

        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();
        var result = request.downloadHandler.text;
        getTXStatus data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<getTXStatus>(result);
        Debug.Log(result);
        ethTXStatus = data.status;

    }
```

Getting this **error:**

> JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing
>   value: {. Path 'result', line 1, position 39.
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringValue
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.ReadType readType) (at
>   <2c34b75de3fc4b43babbd260b14ffeeb>:0)
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsString () (at
>   <2c34b75de3fc4b43babbd260b14ffeeb>:0)

If I do it without the property "result" it returns 1 (the first status).

Comment: when you use jsonproperty, you are defining what the name of key will be in the json. Plus, the result in your json is an object, not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{"status":"1","message":"OK","result":{"status":"0"}}
```

To Deserialize the above json properly, you will need to use the following two classes.

```
public class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public Result Result { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize the json to `RootObject` and get the `result.status`.

```
 var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
 string status = jsonObj.Result.Status; // status will be 0.
```